# What is the reason for size reduction after conversion from mkv to mp4 with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, size

I converted a larger group of mkvs to mp4 (with the commandline:

```
for i in $(ls *.mkv); do ffmpeg -i $i ${i/mkv/mp4}; done
```

but also some with

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv video.mp4
```

The outcome differs in size from the input, though I cannot see any difference (in my video player) and MediInfo confirms, that apsect/ratio and codecs are the same, only bitrate is smaller. In most case, the file is much smaller.

What is the reason? Does ffmpeg get rid of superflouos bitrate with no info?

(sorry for noob hypothesis)

Comment: lower bitrate would mean smaller file of course. I guess you're asking why ffmpeg uses lower bitrate? without specifying any bitrate or quality settings, each encoder does have a "default", which probably results in a lower bitrate on the output

Answer (score 0):

Any time you tell ffmpeg to convert files without options you *will* be losing quality.

A large difference indicates that the "standard" default quality settings chosen by ffmpeg are significantly different to the original. It *might* be that ffmpeg is using better compression methods which achieve a similar quality for a lower bitrate, but it could also mean that it has simply discarded a lot of fine detail which you might see if you compared every pixel in a single frame of the source and destination.

Even if ffmpeg uses better quality encoder options there is going to be at least some "quality" or data that is lost.

The difference may not be detectable by your eyes, but transcoding always loses *some* data. You are fully decoding a frame of video data, and then re-encoding it. The encoding process will *always* throw away some detail due to the approximations used by the encoder. Every subsequent time you re-encode the file will throw away *some* data and contribute to [generation loss.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss)

If all you are wanting to do is change the container of the video from mkv to mp4 and keep all the data in the original then you'd want a command like

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy output.mp4
```

Which will copy the video and audio data exactly as it is stored in the original and simply change the surrounding container data. There is no re-encoding done and no data lost at all, the data is simply rearranged to suit the mp4 format.

Answer (score 0):

OK thank you. I just made further tests with a couple of GOP1 encoded mp4s and, indeed, the outcome is compressed and shuttles less easily. Still I wonder, what these default compression is. It's not that bad a choice of compression I have to say.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).